# JPA2 -- how to auto remove one direction many-to-one mapping data on `many` side?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, ejb

First CascadeType.Remove is not an option because the client side database may not support cascade operation.

I guess OrphanRemoval = true only handle @OneToXXX relationships.

How about `many-to-one` relationships?

For example a `many-to-one` mapping like this:

```
public class Order{
    ....
    @ManyToOne
    private Customer customer;
    .....
}
```

In Customer entity there is no mapping to Order which make the relationship become one-direction.

Then how can we `remove all orders from a customer before removing that customer`? Is there a simple automatic way to handle that or we have to implement the code explicitly via service layer and call something like `findOrdersByCustomer(long customer_id)` then remove them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to use `@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE)`. JPA cascading doesn't use the database's cascading, as far as i know. You would need to define the relationship on the Customer to be able to do that, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you'll need to find all the orders and remove them. Or you can also execute a JPQL query deleting everything:

```
delete from Order o where o.customer = :customer
```

Note that your note about CascadeType.REMOVE is wrong: it's JPA that executes the cascade, and not the database. It's thus supported whatever the database is.

Comment: Thank you. I heard some of the db providers don't support cascade action. So in this case do you think it is OK to apply `CascadeType.Remove` to handle the job then avoid big chunk of code change and also it is compatible to all db platform regardless of vendor? We really prefer some kind of automation from JPA.

Comment: It's OK, but the annotation must be on the other side of the association, which means it must become a bidirectional association.